# How to dump tensorflow XLA LLVM IR?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-xla

I used to use the following command in Tensorflow 1.2:

`export TF_XLA_FLAGS='--dump_ir_before_passes=true --dump_temp_products_to=./tmp'`

for dumping LLVM IR in Tensorflow. However, the definition file of this flag [link_to_the_flag_definition](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/927f811b0303e51126531c135f8b093383de2d6d/tensorflow/compiler/xla/legacy_flags/gpu_backend_lib_flags.cc#L45) is removed in Tensorflow 1.3 and I wonder now how can I get LLVM IR dump?

Here's a test file for your convenience:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
from tensorflow.python.client import timeline
import json

run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
sess = tf.Session()
jit_scope = tf.contrib.compiler.jit.experimental_jit_scope
x = tf.placeholder(np.float32, shape=[1000000])
y = tf.placeholder(np.float32, shape=[1000000])
c = tf.constant(0.1)

with jit_scope():
  z = tf.add(tf.scalar_mul(0.1,x), y)
  ix = np.ones((1000000), dtype=np.float32)
  iy = np.ones((1000000), dtype=np.float32)
  sess.run(z,
           feed_dict={x: ix, y: iy},
           options=tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE),
           run_metadata=run_metadata)
  trace = timeline.Timeline(step_stats=run_metadata.step_stats)
  with open('timeline.ctf.json', 'w') as trace_file:
    trace_file.write(trace.generate_chrome_trace_format())
```

Comment: someone on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/xla-dev probably knows

Answer (score 0):

I have found the flag `--xla_dump_ir_to` here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11462. It was added in Tensorflow 1.3.